# Rspec does not work correctly with Rails3, FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to get Rspec up and running but ran into the following issue when calling `rspec spec` from the command line:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     undefined method `request=' for #<Name:0x000001033c1be0>
```

This seems to be an issue with a combination of certain gems but I cannot figure out what´s wrong with my setup:

Here it is:

```
rails -v
Rails 3.0.9
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
rvm -v
rvm 1.6.2
```

My Gemfile looks like this (I skip irrelevant gems):

```
group :development, :test do
 gem 'factory_girl_rails'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
 gem 'webrat'
end
```

**Addition:**

I added the following line to spec_helper.rb, in order to fix the error that is described [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/212167).

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup
```

Any hints?

Comment: try gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile I solved the issue.

The above described issue occured when I set up my first controller test.

```
describe MyController do
  describe "#index" do
    it "responses successfully" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

To get rid of the problem I had to move the above mentioned line from spec_helper directly into the ControllerSpec.

```
describe MyController do
  include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup

  describe "#index" do
    it "responses successfully" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Go back to work ;-)

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution didn't work for me :-(